# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PlantingBlock.id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, cakephp, stored-procedures

I need to pass a string to a stored procedure using cakephp and mysql.

Here is the string i'm passing to stored procedure,

```
PlantingBlock.id IN (13,10)
```

below is my stored procedure,

```
SET whereClause = " AND 1 = 1 ";
IF(in_clause IS NULL OR in_clause = '') THEN
    SET whereClause = CONCAT(whereClause, ' AND ',in_clause);
END IF;

SET statement = 'SELECT PlantingBlock.* FROM (
    SELECT PB.*, 
    B.block,
    V.variety,
    ST.size_type,
    PLA.date AS plant_date,
    PLA.week_no,
    C.crop,
    C.id AS crop_id
    FROM lf_planting_blocks AS PB,
         lf_blocks AS B,
         lf_properties AS P,
         lf_property_types AS PT,  
         lf_size_types AS ST,
         lf_varieties AS V,
         lf_plantings AS PLA,
         lf_crops AS C
    WHERE
        PB.block_id = B.id
        AND B.property_id = P.id
        AND P.property_type_id = PT.id
        AND B.size_type_id = ST.id
        AND PB.variety_id = V.id
        AND V.crop_id = C.id
        AND PB.planting_id = PLA.id
        AND PB.plant_still_active = true
        AND B.is_deleted = false
        AND P.is_deleted = false
        AND PT.is_deleted = false
        AND ST.is_deleted = false
        AND V.is_deleted = false
        AND C.is_deleted = false';

SET statement = CONCAT(statement, whereClause, ') AS PlantingBlock ORDER BY PlantingBlock.plant_date DESC');
```

This gives an error called,
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PlantingBlock.id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to add a condition to an inner select while referring to `id` column using an alias that gave to this subquery.

Therefore you either close subquery with parenthesis and apply `WHERE` clause to your outer `SELECT`

```
SELECT PlantingBlock.* 
FROM 
(
   ...
) AS PlantingBlock
 WHERE PlantingBlock.id IN (13,10) 
 ORDER BY PlantingBlock.plant_date DESC
```

or better yet just refer to id field in your inner select.

```
SELECT PlantingBlock.* 
FROM 
(
   ...
   AND PB.id IN (13,10)
) AS PlantingBlock
 ORDER BY PlantingBlock.plant_date DESC
```