# "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054" when using a custom primary key in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to build a drop-down list in CakePHP 2.x with the following code:

Controller

```
$Propertytype=$this->Propertytype->find("list",array("fields" => array("Propertytype.propertytype_id,Propertytype.propertytype_name,Propertytype.propertytype_id"),"order" => array("Propertytype.propertytype_id" => "desc"),"conditions" => array("Propertytype.propertytype_status" => "0")));   
$this->set("propertytype",$Propertytype);
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input("propertytype",array("class"=>"form-control","data-style"=>"btn-white",
                    "data-live-search"=>"true","label"=>false,"data-size"=>"5","required"=>"required","options"=>$propertytype));
?>
```

I am not using `Propertytype.id` as primary key. I renamed it to `Propertytype.Propertytype_id`. But when I run the query, it's asking for `Propertytype.id`.

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Propertytype.id' in 'field list'
```

How can I change it to `Propertytype.property_id` as option value?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479050/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-plantingblock-id-in-field-list. same error solved

Comment: I am not using Propertytype.id column . I renamed it as Propertytype.Propertytype_id . But if I run that query its asking for Propertytype.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `$primaryKey` in class `Propertytype`:

```
class Propertytype extends AppModel 
{
    public $primaryKey = 'property_id';
}
```

You also have to write your query using the right syntax:

```
$Propertytype=$this->Propertytype->find("list",array(
    "fields" => array(
        "Propertytype.propertytype_id",
        "Propertytype.propertytype_name"
    ),
    "order" => array("Propertytype.propertytype_id" => "desc"),
    "conditions" => array("Propertytype.propertytype_status" => "0")
));
```

You forgot the quotes.